# How to Scroll horizontaly to a particular div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to do is make it so that if you clicking on a button, it scrolls horizontzly(smoothly) to a specific div on the page.
How to do that?

Comment: @RinoRaj thats works with vertical scroll

Comment: Then change `scrollTop` to `scrollLeft` and `offset().top` to `offset().left`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure about your problem conditions, but you can try some like that:

```
$( '#your_button' ).on( 'click', function() {
    $( 'html, body' ).animate( {
        scrollLeft: $( '#your_div' ).offset().left
    }, 1000 );
} );
```

Comment: It may be left or right

Comment: @maGuru `scrollLeft` doesn't mean scroll to the left...

Comment: @maGuru, probably you misled because of `scrollLeft`. Be sure, it can move left or right, depends on your current position.

Comment: @legotin when we do multiple click on the same button it misbehaves

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.scrollTo plugin](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo).

Answer (score 0):

You can use animate from jQuery in the following way (click the red div, your button):

https://jsfiddle.net/7a40qo2x/7/

---

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
  $("#button").animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: '+=' + $('#destination').offset().left
  }, 1000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```